# Named parameter in PowerShell showing as Positional

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a simple function which has two parameters. I didn't mention them as positional but still, when I check the help for that function it is automatically assigning them a position. How can I force them to be named parameter only (don't accept value by position)?

```
Function Test-Params
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $Param1,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $Param2
    )

    Write-Host "$Param1 $Param2"
}
```

When I check the help for this function or try to run the function by providing parameter positional values it works (but it shouldn't work):

```
Test-Params test1 test2
test1 test2
```

Help output:

```
help Test-Params -Full

NAME
    Test-Params

SYNTAX
    Test-Params [-Param1] <Object> [[-Param2] <Object>]  [<CommonParameters>]


PARAMETERS
    -Param1 <Object>

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    0
        Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
        Parameter set name           (All)
        Aliases                      None
        Dynamic?                     false

    -Param2 <Object>

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    1
        Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
        Parameter set name           (All)
        Aliases                      None
        Dynamic?                     false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> By default, all function parameters are positional. Windows PowerShell
>   assigns position numbers to parameters in the order in which the
>   parameters are declared in the function. To disable this feature, set
>   the value of the PositionalBinding argument of the CmdletBinding
>   attribute to $False.

[Source.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)

So your function looks like this:

```
Function Test-Params
{
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $Param1,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $Param2
    )

    Write-Host "$Param1 $Param2"
}
```

Comment: Good to know; with `PositionalBinding=$false` in place, use parameter-specific `Position=<n>` attributes (e.g., `[Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]` to explicitly make select parameters positional.